# Why does the meta community user not have the Stack Exchange logo as the profile picture?

Tags: support, profile-page

Why does the [meta community user](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) alone have the photography site logo as the profile picture? In Photography [main site's community user](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has the Stack Exchange logo.

In all other Stack Exchange sites, the main and meta sites' community users have the Stack Exchange logo as the profile picture.

Is this a [bug](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) ?

[image: Meta user]

Comment: It does seem seem to be an inconsistency, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's a bug -- it might just be a configuration issue. We don't hear much from Community♦ on meta, though, so changing it might not be a high priority.